# Same key allowed in single array

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I have used mongodb database using php mongodb drivers. New mongodb driver follow some criteria to execute the query. In my code i required two OR condition. When i create an array with two OR condition in this condition array with same key appends. Actually i want same key in my array

Below are my created array structure:-

```
            Array
            (
                [listingStatus] => Active
                [$or] => 
                    Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [propertyType.propertyType] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                                    (
                                        [pattern] => ^single family
                                        [flags] => i
                                    )
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [propertySubType.propertySubType] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                                    (
                                        [pattern] => ^single family
                                        [flags] => i
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [$or] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [address.fullStreetAddress] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                                            (
                                                [pattern] => ^florida
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [address.postalCode] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                                            (
                                                [pattern] => ^florida
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [address.city] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                                            (
                                                [pattern] => ^florida
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [mlsNumber] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object
                                            (
                                                [pattern] => ^florida
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
```

Above are my create array in this array i used array_push method but mongodb required second OR condition out side of inner array and above code returns me to create new array while in second OR condition.

Below are my code :-

```
            $dataSend = array('listingStatus' => 'Active'); 

              $propCondition[] = array('propertyType.propertyType' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$text", 'i'));
              $propCondition[] = array('propertySubType.propertySubType' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$text", 'i'));

              $dataSend['$or'] =  $propCondition;

              $nameCondition = [];

              $nameCondition[] = array('address.fullStreetAddress' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$request->list", 'i'));
              $nameCondition[] = array('address.postalCode' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$request->list", 'i'));
              $nameCondition[] = array('address.city' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$request->list", 'i'));
              $nameCondition[] = array('mlsNumber' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$request->list", 'i'));

              $dataSend1['$or'] =  $nameCondition;
              array_push($dataSend, $dataSend1);  
              print_r($dataSend);
```

Here i have created data send array in my first array and data send array is my second array i try to push second array in first array.

My expected result is while array push second array do not create array is push like a object. in my array first key is listing-Status, second key is $or and last key $or goes in array actually it is display in outside of array.